# mysql - Trigger check value before update

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to make a trigger that check if the salary of an employee is lower than the one of its manager after an update and abort the update if it does.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Employee_BeforeUpdate
 BEFORE UPDATE ON Employee
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM Manager, Manages
     WHERE NEW.eid = Manages.eid
     AND Manager.mid = Manages.mid
     AND NEW.salary > Manager.salary)
   THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = 'Error message';
   END IF;
 END;
```

I'm having a syntax error (1064) near '' at line 9 and I can't figure why. Also is it the right way to do the trigger ?

(MySql Version 5.7.23-0ubuntu.18.04.1)

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (eid char(5), salary integer, primary key(eid));
CREATE TABLE Manager (mid char(5), salary integer, primary key(mid));
CREATE TABLE Manages (mid char(5), eid char(5) , primary key (mid,eid),
                      foreign key(mid) references Manager(mid),
                      foreign key(eid) references Employee(eid));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to redefine Delimiter to something else (eg: `$$`), instead of (`;`).
- Also as a safety measure, check if the same name trigger already exists or not (`DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS`)
- At the end, redefine the `DELIMITER` to `;`

Change the trigger to as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Employee_BeforeUpdate $$
CREATE TRIGGER Employee_BeforeUpdate
 BEFORE UPDATE ON Employee
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM Manager, Manages
     WHERE NEW.eid = Manages.eid
     AND Manager.mid = Manages.mid
     AND NEW.salary > Manager.salary)
   THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = 'Error message';
   END IF;
 END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Didn't work, now it give the following error "Error 1604 (42000) near 'DELIMITER' at line 1".

Comment: @Oppac a space is needed between `END` and `$$` Typo - i am fixing it. please check the updated answer in a minute

Comment: I tried the updated answer but I still have the same error. Also I don't know if its relevant but the trigger is the only thing in my sql file.

Comment: @Oppac maybe If conditions needs some rework. I am doubtful if `IF EXISTS` can be used like this. Can you give me `create table` statement for both the tables. Just relevant fields will be enough. I will try on my local and come back with fix.

Comment: @Oppac I just reproduced your tables on my local machine. I could successfully create the trigger. Are you sure that you are copying the whole thing together and creating the trigger ?

Comment: I edited it to the question. There is three tables Employee, Manager and the relation between them Manages.

Comment: @Oppac yeah I just used your statements also. Recreated it in my local. And added trigger. It worked fine. I am also on MySQL 5.7

Comment: @Oppac check if there are no special characters while you are copying the syntax. Copy the code from here. Put it into some text editor like notepad, gedit etc. It should remove any special characters coming in. Then try running this sql query in phpmyadmin, mysql workbench etc

Comment: Yes, I have done a copy/paste of your answer (in Atom) then I used "source path/filename.sql" in the mysql shell. I have done a "show triggers;" and the trigger exists. I still have the error but despite it the trigger is created. I'm a little confused to be honest ...

Comment: @Oppac I think sourcepath/filename.sql method is probably introducing some extra linebreak / etc causing it to give warnings. However, the query is perfectly allright, and if you run in on phpmyadmin/ mysql workbench etc, you will see it is fine. nevertheless, I believe that your problem is solved. If you are satisfied, you may kindly upvote and mark it as accepted answer. thanks :)